# How to make an opened application stay open after Python command prompt is closed?

Tags: python, cmd, subprocess

I'm making a script that opens Visual Studio through a command prompt. The Visual Studio is opened successfully but if I close the command prompt that the script was run from, the application Visual Studio is closed as well. How can I have it so where after the Vis Studio is opened, I can close the cmd prompt and have Vis Studio still be open?

Here's the cmd I'm using to open Vis Stud

subprocess.call([address + "\Code.exe"])

Open up Command Prompt -> Enter Script.py -> *VS Opens -> Close Command Prompt -> *VS Closes

Comment: How do you execute your script? I can't reproduce your behavior. I start *Python*, open *VStudio*, close the *Python* window, and *VStudio* remains open. Need more details.

Comment: I'm running it from a command prompt

Comment: Why are you running Python at the command prompt to launch VS?

Comment: Not entirely sure. My script will be run from a .bat file is all I know. My coworker is the one integrating it so I couldn't really tell you. This is just the information he gave me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`subprocess.call()` will remain running for as long as Visual Studio runs, and killing it will apparently kill VS too.

You can detach the two by running `subprocess.Popen([address + r'\code.exe'])`
instead.

Comment: ... I think. I would not be surprised if the process model on Windows turned out to be odd.

Comment: Got it! Just changed subprocess.call to subprocess.Popen. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

You can use an ampersand (&) to end your command. This will perform the action but return the terminal to you allowing you to execute other commands (including closing the terminal again).

Comment: I tried this -->
subprocess.call([address + "\Code.exe"])&

with no luck

Comment: This would work on Unix-like platforms if you had the command in a string and added `shell=True` but none of these seem to be true here.